# How to create folder,save file and run java command in client machine using node.js and express.js

Tags: node.js, express

My requirement is to create a folder, save jar and execute in client machine. would it be possible to do so.
if so support me with module information

Thank you in advance.

code to run command for creating directory

```
var username = process.env['USERPROFILE'];
var mkdir = 'mkdir ' username+ DOWNLOAD_DIR;
mkdirSync(DOWNLOAD_DIR);
var mkdirSync = function (path) {
  try {
 fs.mkdirSync(path);
} catch(e) {
 if ( e.code != 'EEXIST' ) throw e;
}
}
```

if i run above code it is creating folder in server

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "client machine".

If you control the client machine, you could setup [an ssh server](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) with sftp or scp to upload the file, and expose either a web interface with express, or a direct shell connection to [exec a jar](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) file.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for suggestion. i do not have access to client machine ,so i am looking to create folder from a web app and place jar in it. i tried to execute command from browser but it is not executing in client machine. adding sample code to the question.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do now and it is not possible. You cannot run node, java, or any other program you please from a browser, you can only write javascript that runs in the browser and you cannot get access to the client fs or shell from there. You would have to write a program that the client downloads and installs on his machine that would execute the tasks you want...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, i opted for windows base application for my requirement